# Check duplicates values in each row and column in 2D Array

Tags: prolog

I am reading a PDF note on a game in `Prolog` which is `Hitori` , I came to the following code

```
abr([]).
abr([_]):-!.
abr([C, C|Cs]):- C \= 0, abr([C|Cs]).
abr([C1, C2|Cs]):- C1 \= C2, abr([C2|Cs]).

abs([]):- !.
abs([Cs|Css]):- abr(Cs), !, abs(Css).

ab(P):- transpose(C, Ccol), abs(C), abs(Ccol).
```

`P` arg stands for 2D array and its initial value

```
-1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1
```

As well as `P` will change its value each time so it can test if an element can be replaced with `zero`

Actually i could not get the above code but i think it checks for validation of changing the element to `zero`

So my question is what does the above code do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the variable of the `ab` predicate should be `C` not `P`.

The `ab/1` predicate takes as input a square matrix of integers in the form:

```
[[0, 4, 0], [2, 0, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

It returns true if there are no two consecutive `0`s in any row or column. This must have something to do with the Hitori rule: "black cells cannot be adjacent, although they can be diagonal to one another".